# How to set Datetime as type for a column on Codeigniter migration

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, migration

I am doing a migration file, and there is a field on a table wich type should be DateTime, and the default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. What I have until now is the next:

```
'date'  => array(
    'type' => 'DATETIME',
),
```

I think it is right... but I still need set the default value... definitely, what I want to do is make the translation from sql to codeigniter migration of this:

```
`date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [this answer](https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-607.html) in the codeigniter forum. Basically, it says that I can use `created_at  timestamp default current_timestamp`instead of key->value array. And there are other interesant things like 'on update':

```
'updated_at' => array(
     'type' => 'varchar',
     'constraint' => 250,
     'null' => true,
     'on update' => 'NOW()'
)
```

I hope it can to help anyone on future.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to Codeigniter migration:

```
$this->dbforge->add_field(array(
                    'id' => array(
                            'type' => 'INT',
                            'constraint' => 5,
                            'unsigned' => TRUE,
                            'auto_increment' => TRUE
                    ),
                    'first_name' => array(
                            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                            'constraint' => '50',
                            'null'=>false,
                    ),
                    'last_name' => array(
                            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                            'constraint' => 50,
                             'null'=>false,
                    ),
                    'email' => array(
                            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                            'constraint' => 100,
                            'unique' => true,
                             'null'=>false,
                    ),
                    'mobile' => array(
                            'type' => 'BIGINT',
                            'constraint' => 15,
                             'null'=>true,
                    ),
                    'password' => array(
                            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                            'constraint' => 255,
                            'null'=>false,
                    ),
                    'image' => array(
                            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                            'constraint' => 255,
                            'null'=>true,
                    ),
                    'status' => array(
                            'type' => 'TINYINT',
                            'constraint' => 3,
                            'default'=>1,
                    ),
                    'delete_status' => array(
                            'type' => 'TINYINT',
                            'constraint' => 3,
                            'default'=>1,
                    ),
                    'created_date datetime default current_timestamp',
                    'updated_date datetime default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp', 
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.Need to use `timestamp`.See an example below..

```
   'created_at' => array('type' => 'timestamp')
```

Comment: Thanks @Hek but what I was looking for was the answer I wrote below. Anyway, really thanks.